# Navigation bar in angular 1.5 app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I'm learning Angular and I'm trying to do a global navigation bar across all angular (1.5) app.
So, to do that navigation bar I've created a directive

navigation.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="header">
      ...
      non important tags
      ...
          <li ng-if="!session.logged"><a href="#/login">Enter</a></li>
          <li ng-if="session.logged"><a ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>

</nav>
```

navigation.js

```
export default function navigation(Auth, Session) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: directivesPath + "navigation.html",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.session = Session.sessionData();

      scope.logout = function() {
        Auth.logout();
        scope.session = Session.sessionData();
        window.location = "#/";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've put than directive in an index.html like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="es" ng-app="movieApp">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <navigation></navigation>
    <div ui-view></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

And I have controllers, for example these two

```
UsersCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "$http", "Session"];

export function UsersCtrl($scope, $http, Session) {
  $http.get('http://localhost:3000/users').success(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.users = data.data;
    $scope.session= Session.sessionData();
  });
}

export default angular.module('movieControllers').controller("LoginCtrl", ["$scope", "$rootScope", "Auth", "Session",
  function($scope, $rootScope, Auth, Session) {
    console.log("User is logged? " + Auth.loggedIn());
    if (Auth.loggedIn() === true) {
      window.location = "#/users/" + Auth.currentUser.username;
    }

    const button = document.getElementById('login');
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
      const username = document.login.username.value;
      const password = document.login.password.value;

      Auth.login({username: username, password: password}, function() {
        $scope.session= Session.sessionData();
        window.location = "#/users/" + username;
        // $scope.$digest();
      });
    });
}]);
```

The `Auth` and `Session` services just make a call to the backend, keep the
user data and retrieve that user data.

The problem is that when I login, the app redirect to the show of the user, but
the nav still showing `<li>Enter</li>`, but if I refresh the browser the nav show
correctly the `<li>Logout</li>` ant the `<li>Enter</li>` is hidding.

If I put the navigation directive inside the template of a controller it
behaves correctly.

What I'm doing incorrectly?

(Sorry for my English, I'm still learning the language too)

Answer (score 0):

Your directive does not watch for `session` changes. When you assign your `session` object  in your link function you may wrap it in `$apply` call to inform about the changes, like that:

```
function navigation(Auth, Session) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: directivesPath + "navigation.html",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.session = Session.sessionData();
      });

      scope.logout = function() {
        Auth.logout(); 

        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.session = Session.sessionData();
        });
        window.location = "#/";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Better yet, look how isolate scope in directives work (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and check $watch function as well.